# _lsprof.c profiler behaviour towards python multi-threading

Tags: python, multithreading

This is a question about Python native c file _lsprof. 
How does _lsprof.profile() profiler counts total time spent on a function f in a multi-threaded program if the execution of f is interrupted by another thread?

For example:

def f():
  linef1
  linef2
  linef3

def g():
  lineg1
  lineg2

And at the execution we have, f and g not being in the same thread:

linef1
linef2
lineg1
linef3
lineg2

Then will the total runtime of f be perceived as the amount of time needed to do:

linef1
linef2
linef3

or will it be the effective latency time:

linef1
linef2
lineg1
linef3

in the results of _lsprof.profile()?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the [documentation for setprofile](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.setprofile):

> The function is thread-specific, but
>   there is no way for the profiler to
>   know about context switches between
>   threads, so it does not make sense to
>   use this in the presence of multiple
>   threads.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this answer! Actually I am running one profiler in each context, so the question make sense. From the tests I made the profiler would measure "linef1 linef2 linef3" in the above example.